# Queryable WHERE Contains String, Int, DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, iqueryable

I am working this line of code:

```
query = query.Where(p => 
  p.ChckNumber.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
  p.BankAccount.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
  p.Description.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
  p.CheckAmount.ToString().Contains(globalSearch) || 
  p.ClearedDate.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
  p.SentDate.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()));
```

With this line of code I am basically doing a search, it seems to work fine when `globalSearch` is a `string` and the column like `BankAccount` and `Description` are `varchar`, however, when `globalSearch` is an `Int` or `DateTime` (-2233 or 4/9/2013) for the columns `CheckAmount (int)`, `ClearedDate (DateTime)`, `SentDate (DateTime)`, it returns 0 rows, and if `globalSearch` matches an `int` in `ChckNumber` **it works!**

What Am I doing wrong?

I ran this query in SQL Server:

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ClearedDate) FROM myTable`

and all my dates return Sep 9 2017 If `globalSearch` is Sep 10 2017 it works, but it does not work for the format I need as: 9/9/2017

Comment: So if user types "2" you want to return all items where any numeric or date field contains 2 (like number 112 or date 01/03/2017). Seems not very useful.

Comment: Please check what query is fired with the help of sql profiler. this will give you an idea of how to tweak your linq.  i am guessing its something to do with how ToString() is converting the data to string and in which format.

Comment: try to debug your code step by step , 1- try to check if "Tostring" method working properly on your input data or not. 2-try to check if  date time format in your sql-server database is consistent with your date time input

Comment: Have you tried to use format in `ToString`? Ex: `p.ClearedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: What is your logic around the dates? Do you want exact date match?

Comment: No examples for `globalSearch` and `CheckAmount` / `ClearedDate` given where the issue occurs. Not enough explanation what should be possible. This question should be updated or is not worth to be answered otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not care if globalSearch is an Int because you should always convert it to a string, unless a DateTime and you should not care if a column is a varchar or an Int because you are always converting columns to strings, unless DateTime.

Note, I make the assumption, based on your comments that you are comparing just month,day and year and are not concerned about the time for ClearedDate

I see three potential issues with your code:

1. You do not convert globalSearch to a string for column CheckAmount
2. You do not check for nulls for any of your columns before calling .ToString, perhaps all of your columns do NOT Allow Nulls
3. Your code is not very readable it is hard for human eyes to spot inconsistencies.

Here is more readable code that converts globalSearch to a string once and every time because again, you do not convert globalSearch to a string for CheckAmount:

```
var gsStr = globalSearch.ToString();
var gsDate = DateTime.MinDate;
if(globalSearch.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
{
    gsDate = globalSearch;
}
query = query.Where(p => p.ChckNumber.ToString().Contains(gsStr) 
|| p.BankAccount.ToString().Contains(gsStr) 
|| p.Description.ToString().Contains(gsStr) 
|| p.CheckAmount.ToString().Contains(gsStr) 
|| p.ClearedDate.Date == gsDate.Date
|| p.SentDate.ToString().Contains(gsStr));
```

If you are using C# 6.0 you can use the new Null Propagation Operator to protect from errors if any of your columns do allow nulls now or in the future:

```
var gsStr = globalSearch.ToString();
var gsDate = DateTime.MinDate;
if(globalSearch.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
{
    gsDate = globalSearch;
}
query = query.Where(p => p.ChckNumber?.ToString().Contains(gsStr) 
|| p.BankAccount?.ToString().Contains(gsStr) 
|| p.Description?.ToString().Contains(gsStr) 
|| p.CheckAmount?.ToString().Contains(gsStr) 
|| p.ClearedDate?.Date == gsDate.Date
|| p.SentDate?.ToString().Contains(gsStr));
```

Converting globalSearch ToString for CheckAmount Contains may fix your issues, making your code more readable and protect against nulls will make it easier to debug if it does not fix bug.

Comment: The question has sql tag, so there's a probably Entity Framework used and if so, code with .ToString() will most likely not work there.

Comment: I ran this query in SQL Server SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ClearedDate) FROM myTable and all my dates return Sep 9 2017 If globalSearch is Sep 10 2017 it works, but it does not work for the format I need it 9/9/2017

Comment: @user979331 I updated my answer to compare to DateTime.Dates

Comment: @user979331 The answer is good, try it. Additionaly when you use CONVERT for dates you should add as parameter the desirable format, have alook here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 2):

Your code will return rows for which the first field in the query matches the query term. Is that a realistic requirement? I suggest not. The query term must be destined for a known, specific field.

Are you really interested in finding the the query term as a substring of your field contents? At least in the case of the integer and date fields, that seems unlikely, though as you haven't stated the values that your query term can contain, it isn't possible to say for sure.

It's not necessary to convert varchar fields `.ToString()` as they are already strings. Similarly, if you provide a query term of an appropriate type when querying `DateTime` or `Integer` fields, you won't need to convert them either (assuming you are not in fact querying for a substring). That will avoid issues with null field values and will remove more redundant processing.

You may want to redesign your query with these points in mind. Rather than using a "one size fits all" query object, I suggest you take a more deliberate approach.

For example, you could create an query object that contains a nullable property for each query field.

```
public partial class AccountQuery
{
    public string CheckNumber { get; set; }
    public string BankAccount { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? CheckAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ClearedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SentDate { get; set; }
}
```

Add a method to your entity model / DTO to encapsulate the query logic. It accepts an AccountQuery object and matches any non-null properties on it with the corresponding entity property.

```
public class Account
{
    public string CheckNumber { get; set; }
    public string BankAccount { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CheckAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClearedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime SentDate { get; set; }
    public bool Matches(AccountQuery query)
    {
        return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.CheckNumber) && query.CheckNumber == CheckNumber) ||
               (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.BankAccount) && query.BankAccount == BankAccount) ||
               (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.Description) && query.Description == Description) ||
               (query.ClearedDate.HasValue && query.ClearedDate == ClearedDate) ||
               (query.SentDate.HasValue && query.SentDate == SentDate) ||
               (query.CheckAmount.HasValue && query.CheckAmount == CheckAmount);
    }
}
```

Your query then becomes, for example:

```
var aq = new AccountQuery
{
    ClearedDate = DateTime.Today
};
query.Where(p => p.Matches(aq));
```

Note that the logic of this query is not the same as your original code, which as I pointed out above, does not seem realistic.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the Late Answer

Don't use ToString for Numerics

instead check the globalsearch String is NUmeric or not,

if it is numeric then convert it to required field like integer or double.
And as for as  DateTime  concerned,

Use the Date formatter as  p.ClearedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") and no need to format the globalsearch  as it will be in the given format

my solution might be this,

query = query.Where(p => 
  p.ChckNumber==int.TryParse(globalSearch.ToString, out num)?num:globalSearch.ToString(); || 
  p.BankAccount.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
  p.Description.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
  p.CheckAmount==decimal.TryParse(globalSearch.ToString, out num)?num:globalSearch.ToString(); || 
  p.ClearedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
  p.SentDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Contains(globalSearch.ToString()));

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you are looking for correct format of your date try this.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SYSDATETIME(), 103)
```

Answer (score 1):

Single-char date format. We can use a char as the argument for ToString to specify a preset format. These are standard formats.

```
query = query.Where(p => 
p.ChckNumber.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
p.BankAccount.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
p.Description.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
p.CheckAmount.ToString().Contains(globalSearch) || 
p.ClearedDate.ToString("d").Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
p.SentDate.ToString("d").Contains(globalSearch.ToString()));
```

OR

ToShortDateString() is equivalent to the lower case d ToString("d")

```
query = query.Where(p => 
p.ChckNumber.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
p.BankAccount.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
p.Description.ToString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
p.CheckAmount.ToString().Contains(globalSearch) || 
p.ClearedDate.ToShortDateString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()) || 
p.SentDate.ToShortDateString().Contains(globalSearch.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to format your date part

```
 p.ClearedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Contains(globalSearch.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Also try linq Pad or similar tool or any linq helper extension to see what SQL is coming out

Comment: Why use `Contains` here at all? Such date string will never contain any other date string except for itself and in this case is equal to it. So a test for equality would do the same here and might be much faster.

Comment: Agree with you , instead of this i use another approach , first check the date for greater than equal to and than in a nested if (if possible) check for  less than condition also . This approach always work for me even if there is a little bit variation in format (03/03/2017 or 3/3/2017)

Answer (score 1):

You should use format according to your requirement. The all date time format coded by numbers.

> For instance, 110 -> mm-dd-yyyy

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ClearedDate, 110) FROM myTable
```